# AutoOverlap functionality using StitchEngine.dll

Tags: c#, image-stitching

So I am using stitchengine.dll for image stitching. I want to use AutoOverlap functionality. Upon looking through some decomplied code i found that AutoOverlap uses ReanalyseOverlap function to get horizontaloverlap and verticaloverlap.
I tried using it like this:

```
ThumbnailAnalyzerWrapper thumbnailAnalyzerWrapper = new ThumbnailAnalyzerWrapper();
bool working = thumbnailAnalyzerWrapper.ReanalyzeOverlap(2, true, true, false, false, ref horizontalOverlap, ref verticalOverlap);
```

However whatever value I give for horizontaloverlap and verticaloverlap i keep getting back 0. I am confused why it is giving 0 everytime. The image I am using should give value 20 for horizontaloverlap and 1 for verticaloverlap. As I used them in ICE.